# Wine does not want to install on KDE neon

Tags: software-installation, kde, wine, kde-neon

I’m using KDE neon and tried to install Wine. 
However, if I install it, I always get:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) wine-stable:amd64 < none -> 4.0.1~disco @un puN Ib >
Broken wine-stable:amd64 Depends on wine-stable-amd64:amd64 < none | 4.0.1~disco @un uH > (= 4.0.1~disco)
  Considering wine-stable-amd64:amd64 0 as a solution to wine-stable:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed early because of libc6:amd64
Broken wine-stable:amd64 Depends on wine-stable-i386:amd64 < none @un H > (= 4.0.1~disco)
  Considering wine-stable-i386:i386 0 as a solution to wine-stable:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed early because of libc6:i386
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 4.0.1~disco) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 4.0.1~disco)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this? I already tried this: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=154066, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using wine packages built for the wrong version of Ubuntu (Disco Dingo, which is Ubuntu 19.04, rather than Bionic Beaver, which is Ubuntu 18.04 and what KDE Neon is based on.) Try changing `disco` to `bionic` in the relevant sources.list entry.

Comment: how do you change?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/197564/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-my-etc-apt-sources-list